# Awk: Is there a way to specify command line options in awkfile?

Tags: awk

Suppose I have an awk argument like so:

```
awk -F '.' -v foo="bar" '{...}'
```

And I would like to store everything in an awkfile:

```
awk file:
-F '.'
-v foo="bar"

{
    ...
}
```

So that I can shorten the call to simply:

```
awk -f awkfile
```

---

The above is written in pseudocode, but there must be a way to do it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add it to the `BEGIN` Section

```
BEGIN {FS=".";foo="bar"} ++++ code
```